# Unable to connect to website a second time

Tags: python, pandas, request, urllib

I am trying to retrieve data from IAEA database using their suggested code with Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

GET_ALL_ISOTOPES = 'https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/v0/data?fields=ground_states&nuclides=all'
GET_ISOTOPE_LEVELS = 'https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/v0/data?fields=levels&nuclides={n}{symbol}'
GET_FISSION_PRODUCTS = 'https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/v0/data?fields=cumulative_fy&parents={n}{symbol}'

def lc_read_csv(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0')
    req.set_proxy('firewall', 'http')
    content = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    df = pd.read_csv(content)
    return df

df = lc_read_csv(GET_ALL_ISOTOPES)
```

The first time I ran this, it worked great. I made some changes to my module and reimported it, and then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1322, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1271, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1031, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 969, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1441, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 945, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 919, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 278, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    df = lc_read_csv(GET_ALL_ISOTOPES)
  File "C:\Users\ZDZD25R\OneDrive - US Customs and Border Protection\Documents\u238.py", line 32, in lc_read_csv
    content = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

Every subsequent call gives the same result; restarting python gave the same result. Getting the data from the website works fine; it's not down. What is going on. Why can I only retrieve it once and never again for the rest of my life?

Comment: BTW, I have a user agent; that's not the issue

Comment: code works for me all time if I remove `req.set_proxy('firewall', 'http')`. Tested on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu)